# Extract unique subdomains from input file

Tags: linux, regular-expression

I have a .txt file with 2 million lines containing URLs of the same domain, I need to extract only unique subdomains of this list... The problem is when I use the command below, the output return the entire unique URLs, I only need to extract unique subdomain names not the entire URL, without repeat. Any tips? Thanks<3

```
cat all-urls.txt | grep domain.com.br | uniq -u
```

I need the output be like this:

```
https://sub1.domain.com
https://sub2.domain.com
https://sub3.domain.com
https://sub4.domain.com
https://sub5.domain.com
(...)
```

Comment: You should edit your question. Add 'input file', your 'source' file, with your lines (about 5-10 lines), also write what you would like your file (lines) look like after command is run (your desired output)... Of course, if, in your lines, there are sensitive data, remove them...

Comment: *the output return the entire unique URLs, I only need to extract unique subdomain names not the entire URL* -- but the output example you've included in your edit includes the shared **https://** and **domain.com** substrings. Do you want to keep those? A few lines from your input would be very helpful.

Comment: It is always a good idea to provide as much details as possible so we could be able to help and provide better answers. From what I understand, you want something like:  `awk -F'[/.]' '!seen[$3]++ { print $3}' all-urls.txt`

Answer (score 2):

`cut -d/ -f3 all-urls.txt | sort -u`

and then I didn't even have a useless use of `cat`.